# CakeDC users plugin: How can i install cakedc users plugin, i have read the documentation

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0, cakedc

```
https://github.com/cakedc/users/tree/2.0
```

After extracting the cakedc users plugin i copied it to app/Plugin folder.

I ran this command and got error:

```
cake migration all -plugin users
```

Why is this error? It's cakephp-2.0 and after extracting the users plugin, i see the convention of the folders are like cakehp-1.3

```
Error: Shell class MigrationShell could not be found.
#0 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(167): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('migration')
#1 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/cake.php(24): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#3 {main}
```

How can i install this users plugin and use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you installed CakeDC's [Migrations plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations/tree/2.0)?
2. Have you [loaded the plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#installing-a-plugin)?

Comment: I loaded in Bootstrap file, CakePlugin::loadAll(); , still got the same error,

Answer (score 6):

In case someone will search this, here's how to use Migrations and Users plugins from CakeDC with CakePHP 2.x:

1) Make sure you downloaded correct branches (2.0) from git. It can be checked by camel-cased directory names of plugins

2) Place them inside app/Plugins/ with corresponding names: `Migrations` and `Users`

3) make sure you loaded plugins by including them in app/Config/bootstrap.php like:
`CakePlugin::load('Migrations');`

4) to import Users plugins scheme go to app/ and run command `./Console/cake Migrations.migration all --plugin Users`

This sequence worked for me. Hope it will help someone else. If there are any improvements to this - all are welcome.

Comment: Note the `Migrations.migration` syntax.  That's what I spent several hours missing.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is a bit wrong on the docs. For migration, (first install the CakeDC Migrations plugin) you should run ..

```
Console/cake Migrations.migration run all --plugin Users
```